# Visual Studio 2019 Xamarin Forms android emulator failing with message System UI isn't responding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-emulator, visual-studio-2019

Getting an error message, 'System UI isn't responding.' and it gives me the options 'Close app' or 'Wait' when debugging Xamarin.Forms. This is on the emulator that launches. I have set the memory at 512 and the resolution at 800x600 as some have suggested in other threads. I also did a 'factory reset.' Nothing has helped so far.

Are there any other options that may get me past this? I just purchased a Xamarin class from Udemy and can't even get past the first few videos.

[image]

I should mention that I do not think I am short on resources. I have two 500 GB SSD drives and the following memory and processor specs.

[image]

Comment: This usually related to the host's general performance (CPU,GPU,RAM,Storage). Just leave the emulator running until it fully boots (just ignore the alerts) and once it is fully running (you can watch the boot process via `logcat`) then try deploying a debug test app from Visual Studio. FYI: Do not close the emulator window in between debug sessions, just leave it running.

Comment: First of all, please make sure your have enabled the Hardware acceleration for emulator,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows     If you enabled it, please delete this emulator, create a emulator like this screenshot.https://imgur.com/a/ZyBakKc

Comment: Leon Lu - MSFT, this worked great. I did what you suggested as well as installed the Hyper-V tree as well as the 'Windows Hypervisor Platform' and the emulator boots up much faster and my app is also visible and functional. Thank you.

Comment: @iviouse I post it to anwer, Please mark it as answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, please make sure your have enabled the Hardware acceleration for emulator, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows

If you enabled it, please delete this emulator, create a emulator like this screenshot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih5pP.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by going to Tools in Visual Studio. Tools > Android > Android Device Manager > select and edit property (**hw.gpu.mode**) of emulator to **mesa**